# What is the value of mean so that the probability of random sample mean falling in the observed confidence interval is 95%?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Question: The expression we drive for the 95% confidence interval involves Sn=1/n* sum Xi, i=1 to n, which is a random variable. 
So, the "location" of the confidence interval is a random variable and so it may or may not cover mean_x. However when we actually compute a confidence interval from data, it's no longer a random variable, it's called the "observed" confidence interval, and it's computed as X+-1.96*(s_x/sqrt(n)). 
What would the value of mean_x have to be so that the probability of the random sample mean falls into the observed confidence interval is 95%? Show work.

I am confused about what the question is asking. but this is my work↓

Suppouse for X1, X2,..., Xn have a sample mean of mean_s and standard deviation of std_s.

And sample population of n.

Then mean_s-1.96*std_s＜mean_x＜mean_s+1.96*std_s for all sample mean to be included in the 95% confidence interval.

Since std_s=s_x/sqrt(n)

So am I computing the interval of mean_x?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: As for the math: in introductory courses/materials, for pedagogical purposes people try different phrasing to emphasize certain parts of the logic behind confidence intervals and hypothesis testings. A specific choice of wording might work better for some people but very confusing for you, and there's no need to read too much into the sentences when that happens. Just given them the $\alpha$ level confidence interval (here $\alpha =0.95 = 95\%$).

Comment: My question is that what is the value of the population mean where all sample mean is in the confidence interval of 95%?

Comment: Do we use 95% interval or population mean=sample mean?